# Can Cplex take two sparse matrices as input for Q

Tags: optimization, sparse-matrix, cplex, quadratic-programming

I am trying to minimize a very large binary quadratic programming problem with linear constraints using the [CPLEX MATLAB API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/cplex_matlab_overview.html). However the quadratic function f = x'Qx has a very dense matrix Q. I can rewrite Q with very sparse matrices U and A: Q = U A.

Hence, is there a way to pass these matrices to CPLEX instead of the full matrix Q (which is too large to store)?

Comment: Are you using the C Callable Library and [CPXXcopyquad](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/qpapi/copyquad.html)?  If so, that function already takes a sparse representation of the Q matrix (via qmatbeg, qmatcnt, qmatind, qmatval)....  Have you tried this yet?  What error are you getting?

Comment: I am using the matlab interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with the MATLAB API.  There are two MATLAB API's: the CPLEX for MATLAB Toolbox and the Cplex class.  The corresponding functions/field in each would be [cplexmiqp](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/cplexmiqp-m.html) and [Cplex.Model.Q](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/classCplex.html).  Neither of those allow you to do exactly what you're asking for.

However (I was not previously aware of this), the MATLAB API does accept a single [sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html) for the Q matrix (see also the MATLAB API [programming tips](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/gs_tips.html) section).

For example, these two examples are interchangeable:

```
cplex.Model.Q = [-33     6     0  0;
     6   -22  11.5  0;
     0  11.5   -11  0;
     0     0     0  0];
```

or, using a sparse matrix:

```
cplex.Model.Q = sparse([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3], [-33, 6, 6, -22, 11.5, 11.5, -11], 4, 4)
```

This is more explicit with the other API's (e.g., C Callable Library, C++, Python, etc.).  If you are interested, the examples that are shipped with CPLEX demonstrate how that is done.

Comment: I am not a MATLAB expert, so I was not aware of how to use native sparse matrices in MATLAB nor was I aware that CPLEX accepted them.  I've made the appropriate edits to my answer.  Sorry about any confusion I may have caused with that point.